# Why can not get email message (python, gmail, django)?

Tags: python, django, smtp

all. Have a troubles with email sending in django. 
Have next in my settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxx@gmail.com'
```

Try to call function **send_mail** from **django.core.mail**:

```
 send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
           ['yyyy@coin-host.net', ], fail_silently=False)
```

Have next output:

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>   Subject: Subject here
>   From: xxxx@gmail.com
>   To: yyyy@coin-host.net
>   Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2019 09:57:10 -0000
>   Message-ID: <20190923095710.1383.3314>
>   Here is the message.

But I have not any messages in my mail client. Have checked Spam folder too - it's empty.

Comment: the output shown on your console?

Comment: @Toan Quoc Ho `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8" MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit Subject: Subject here From: xxxx@gmail.com To: yyyy@coin-host.net Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2019 09:57:10 -0000 Message-ID: <20190923095710.1383.3314> Here is the message.`

Comment: If it showed on your console, I worry that some where the code already overridden the EMAIL_BACKEND, `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`. make sure that there is no line of code like this

Comment: @Toan Quoc Ho , yes I have a lot of "----" at the last line of console output

Comment: I mean you should make sure that `EMAIL_BACKEND` not be overridden. Make sure that it always has this value `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'`

Comment: Yes, you was right. I have overridden my `EMAIL_BACKEND` to the `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend`. Have fixed this and all works pretty good. Please make and answer to this question, than I should mark it as True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You email was displayed in the console so seem like your `EMAIL_BACKEND` was overridden by `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend`.
Make sure that there is no line of code which override your `EMAIL_BACKEND` and the value of `EMAIL_BACKEND` setting always is `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`.

Hope that helps!